# Error Installing Guest Additions in Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, guest-additions

I have a problem installing guest additions in my VM using VBox ver4.3.40 ubuntu.

[image: error installing guest additions on client]

As you can see in the screenshot. I am getting an error linux/compiler.h No such file or directory

I can't find the answer just by googling. Any help would be appreciated. My VM OS is red hat 7.2 enigma ( 2002 ). I need to install the guest additions inorder to fix the screen resolution when switching to GUI mode ( as it forces screen resolution to 320X200 ).

Here's my virtualbox version

[image]

and

Here's my virtualbox guest additions

[image: virtualbox version]

Thank you

Comment: Verify that you're using a MATCHING version of the guest additions for our OLD Virtualbox. VBox is up to 6.x by now, if you downloaded THAT version of guest additions I'd suspect it to fail installation.

Comment: @Hannu - I've edited my post and show the vbox ver and the installed guest additions. I think the vbox ver and the guest additions are match ? thank you so much for the reply

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of VirtualBox on the host OS?

Comment: @Ramhound - I am following the instructions in the book Linux in Action. I am new to linux.

Comment: You might want to mention that fact, and the fact, your using Ubuntu 14.10 which would be the reason your using the older version of VirtualBox.

Comment: `$ locate linux/compiler.h` should find at least one compiler.h - how to get that used in the above is beyond me though, unless it IS in a standard location. You might need to install a package (=headers?) that contains `compiler.h` -- to find that package-> `$ apt-file search linux/compiler.h `, and `sudo apt-get install <package>` to get it installed.

Comment: @Hannu running `locate compiler.h` results in /usr/src/linux-2.4.7.10/include/compiler.h the problem is how we can include this file in the make file process.

Comment: more specific: `-I/usr/src/linux-2.4.7.10/include/` or some such needs to appear as the compiler runs (in the first image of yours), this probably needs to be added in a Makefile for VBox, or as "deafult" parameter for gcc.